# HelloWorld MapView displays blank grid

Tags: android, api, view, dictionary, key

I followed the hello world for the map view and all I get is a blank grid that I can zoom around in:

http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html

here is my android manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="us.fubz.helloMap"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>


    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">

        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".helloMap"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I generated the Api-key from my C:\Users\fubz.android\debug.keystore

I am testing it on my original droid using eclipse.

I have no idea what I am doing wrong.  I double checked my code with multiple sources and I still don't understand.  I think the api key is wrong but know way to prove it or know how to get a new one.